# Change state through function within same file but outside struct

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I have a loading screen that should navigate to the **contentview** once a few images have finished loading. I load the images using the first two functions and finally trigger navigation to content view. Navigation is triggered when a state variable **activateNavigation** turns true. The issue is I need to change state in a function outside the struct. I can't seem to figure out how to do this, you can see it in the final code snippet below.

```
LoadingScreen().onAppear(){
   getImages();
   convertImages();
   triggerNavigationToContentView();
}
```

```
struct LoadingScreen: View{
    @State var text = ""
    @State var activateNavigation = false
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    var body: some View{
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                Text("Loading images \(text)")
                    .font(.system(size: 24)).bold()
                    .transition(.slide)
                    .onReceive(timer, perform: {(_) in
                        if self.text.count == 3 {
                            self.text = ""
                        } else {
                            self.text += "."
                        }
                    })
                    .onAppear(){
                        self.text = "."
                    }
                NavigationLink(destination: ContentView(), isActive: $activateNavigation, label: { EmptyView() })
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

```
triggerNavigationToContentView(){
    activateNavigation = true;
}
```

Comment: Use `ObservableObject` view model instead of state for such cases.

Comment: I've tried but I can't pass an ObservableObject to isActive inside NavigationLink, it states expected argument Binding<bool>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inject the binding into your second `View` it should work fine.

```
NavigationLink(destination: ContentView($activateNavigation), isActive: $activateNavigation, label: { EmptyView() })
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @Binding var activateNavigation: Bool
  ...
}
```

Bindings are persisted throughout view routes, so if you now set `activateNavigation` in `ContentView` it will update in `LoadingScreen` too (and vice versa).

You can use Bindings in initialisers for other structs too if you need to trigger the flow elsewhere. I don’t recommend global functions.

Note that using `$activateNavigation` implicitly converts the `@State` into an `@Binding`, no boilerplate needed.

Comment: I've added "@State var activateNavigation: Bool" to loading view and have added your snippet to content view but for self.activateNavigation = activateNavigation I get cannot assign value of type 'Binding<Bool>' to type 'Bool'

Comment: Sorry, got lost in translation that we don't need initializers for `View`. Updated the code snippet, you should get an auto-generated `ContentView.init` which takes a binding.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Binding` inline using the [`init(get:set:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding/init(get:set:)-7ufcp) initializer.

```
...

NavigationLink(
    destination: ContentView(),
    isActive: .init(
        get: { activateNavigation },
        set: { activateNavigation = $0 }
    ),
    label: { EmptyView() }
)

...
```